# streaming image from url, android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I need to load, and update image from URL.

Using AsyncTask, Iam able to load image from URL bt i need to reload image from url for every 10 secs.

Please help me how i can solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

@Praveenb 
try following ,

```
Bitmap bmImg;
void downloadFile(String fileUrl){
URL myFileUrl =null; 
try {
myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); 
    // it will decode the input stream and will load the bitmat in bmImg variable

imView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

following code works fine for me,

```
class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable>{
        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return Util.getImageFromURL(imageURL); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( Drawable d ) {
            getImageIcon().setImageDrawable(d);
        }

}
new DownloadImage().execute();
```

and if you are showing image in list view you should follow this
http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-thumbnail

Comment: Hi sohilvassa,
I see that u are showing image from url in imageview.
 is this image will update continuously from the url?. Please let me know hw i can get this work.

thanks for reply